# Level of `debug()` in R

Tags: r, debugging

Usually, when I call `debug()` on a function in R it just steps through the function, but sometimes it follows the call stack down. I can't figure out why one happens vs the other.

For example, if I have

```
f <- function(x){
  print(x)
}
```

Usually running

```
debug(f)
f("Hello World")
```

Will just show

```
function(x) print(x)
```

Sometimes it will go into the code of the print method itself and I see the method dispatch and

```
function (x, digits = NULL, quote = TRUE, na.print = NULL, print.gap = NULL, 
  right = FALSE, max = NULL, useSource = TRUE, ...) 
{
  noOpt <- missing(digits) && missing(quote) && missing(na.print) && 
    missing(print.gap) && missing(right) && missing(max) && 
    missing(useSource) && missing(...)
  .Internal(print.default(x, digits, quote, na.print, print.gap, 
            right, max, useSource, noOpt))
}
```

Which is not helpful for debugging the function I wrote. Does anyone know how to select whether `debug()` goes down into the call stack? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`debug` by itself never goes down the call stack — it shows you exactly those functions that you are `debug`ging, nothing more, nothing less.

In this particular case, there are two reasons why you find yourself in another function:

1. You accidentally `debug`ged that function as well, i.e. you called `debug(print.default)`.
2. During debugging, you stepped *into* the function. In the R console, this happens when you press <kbd>s</kbd> instead of <kbd>n</kbd> (“step into” instead of “next”). In RStudio, there are appropriate buttons for either action.

Other things that might cause finding yourself inside another function happen when `options(error)` is set appropriately, or when the function contains an explicit call to `browser()`.

Comment: When you debug a S3 generic the debugger takes you to the method, maybe that's what happened to OP as he called `debug(print)`